# Given a string, find its first non-repeating character in only One scan

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

> Given a string, find the first non-repeating character in it. For
>   example, if the input string is “GeeksforGeeks”, then output should be
>   ‘f’.
>
> We can use string characters as index and build a count array.
>   Following is the algorithm.
>
> 1. Scan the string from left to right and construct the count array or
>      HashMap.
> 2. Again, scan the string from left to right and check for
>      count of each  character, if you find an element who's count is 1,
>      return it.

Above problem and algorithm is from [GeeksForGeeks](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/given-a-string-find-its-first-non-repeating-character/)

**But it requires two scan of an array. I want to find first non-repeating character in only one scan.**
I implemented above algorithm [Please check it also on Ideone](http://ideone.com/amNcli):

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author Neelabh
 */
public class FirstNonRepeatedCharacter {
    public static void main(String [] args){
        Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
        String string=scan.next();
        int len=string.length();
        HashMap<Character, Integer> hashMap=new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
        //First Scan
        for(int i = 0; i <len;i++){
            char currentCharacter=string.charAt(i);
            if(!hashMap.containsKey(currentCharacter)){
                hashMap.put(currentCharacter, 1);
            }
            else{
                hashMap.put(currentCharacter, hashMap.get(currentCharacter)+1);
            }
        }
        // Second Scan
        boolean flag=false;
        char firstNonRepeatingChar = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<len;i++){
                char c=string.charAt(i);
                if(hashMap.get(c)==1){
                    flag=true;
                    firstNonRepeatingChar=c;
                    break;
                }
        }
        if(flag==true)
            System.out.println("firstNonRepeatingChar is "+firstNonRepeatingChar);
        else
            System.out.println("There is no such type of character");
    }    
}
```

GeeksforGeeks also suggest efficient method but I think it is also *two scan*. Following solution is from [GeeksForGeeks](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/given-a-string-find-its-first-non-repeating-character/)

> ```
> #include <stdlib.h>
> #include <stdio.h>
> #include <limits.h>
> #define NO_OF_CHARS 256
>
> // Structure to store count of a character and index of the first
> // occurrence in the input string
> struct countIndex {
>    int count;
>    int index;
> };
>
> /* Returns an array of above structure type. The size of
>    array is NO_OF_CHARS */
> struct countIndex *getCharCountArray(char *str)
> {
>    struct countIndex *count =
>         (struct countIndex *)calloc(sizeof(countIndex), NO_OF_CHARS);
>    int i;
>
>    // This is First Scan
>
>    for (i = 0; *(str+i);  i++)
>    {
>       (count[*(str+i)].count)++;
>
>       // If it's first occurrence, then store the index
>       if (count[*(str+i)].count == 1)
>          count[*(str+i)].index = i;
>    }
>    return count;
> }
>
> /* The function returns index of the first non-repeating
>     character in a string. If all characters are repeating
>     then reurns INT_MAX */
> int firstNonRepeating(char *str)
> {
>   struct countIndex *count = getCharCountArray(str);
>   int result = INT_MAX, i;
>
>   //Second Scan
>   for (i = 0; i < NO_OF_CHARS;  i++)
>   {
>     // If this character occurs only once and appears
>     // before the current result, then update the result
>     if (count[i].count == 1 && result > count[i].index)
>        result = count[i].index;
>   }
>
>   free(count); // To avoid memory leak
>   return result;
> }
>
>
> /* Driver program to test above function */
> int main()
> {
>   char str[] = "geeksforgeeks";
>   int index =  firstNonRepeating(str);
>   if (index == INT_MAX)
>     printf("Either all characters are repeating or string is empty");
>   else
>    printf("First non-repeating character is %c", str[index]);
>   getchar();
>   return 0;
> }
> ```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can store 2 arrays: count of each character and the first occurrence(and fill both of them during the first scan). Then the second scan will be unnecessary.

Comment: No, you are not.
Check out the algorithm: http://pastebin.com/2jNUMXuc
Note that the above works only for upper case letters, in ASCII, but it can be easily made to work with lowercase as well.

Comment: What if there are multiple nonrepeating characters ?

Comment: I still would considered this as scanning twice. See my solution at https://stackoverflow.com/a/47176679/58678 which uses a deque and a hashmap and only scans once.

Answer (score 5):

Use String functions of java then you find the solution in only one for loop
The Example is show below

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class firstoccurance {
public static void main(String args[]){
char [] a ={'h','h','l','l','o'};
//Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
String s=new String(a);//sc.next();
char c;
int i;
int length=s.length();
for(i=0;i<length;i++)
{
    c=s.charAt(i);
    if(s.indexOf(c)==s.lastIndexOf(c))
    {
        System.out.println("first non repeating char in a string   "+c);
        break;
    }
    else if(i==length-1)
    {
        System.out.println("no single char");
    }
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In following solution I declare one class **CharCountAndPosition** which stores firstIndex and frequencyOfchar. During the reading string characterwise, firstIndex stores the first encounter of character and frequencyOfchar stores the total occurrence of characters.

We will make array of CharCountAndPosition  **step:1** and Initialize it **step2**.
During scanning the string, Initialize the firstIndex and frequencyOfchar for every character **step3**.
Now In the **step4** check the array of CharCountAndPosition, find the character with frequency==1 and minimum firstIndex
**Over all time complexity is O(n+256), where n is size of string. O(n+256) is equivalent to O(n)** Because 256 is constant.  [Please find solution of this on ideone](http://ideone.com/vSHZen)

```
public class FirstNonRepeatedCharacterEfficient {
        public static void main(String [] args){
            // step1: make array of CharCountAndPosition.
            CharCountAndPosition [] array=new CharCountAndPosition[256];

            // step2: Initialize array with object of CharCountAndPosition. 
            for(int i=0;i<256;i++)
            {
                array[i]=new CharCountAndPosition();
            }

            Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
            String str=scan.next();
            int len=str.length();
            // step 3
            for(int i=0;i<len;i++){
                char c=str.charAt(i);
                int index=c-'a';            
                int frequency=array[index].frequencyOfchar;
                if(frequency==0)
                    array[index].firstIndex=i;
                array[index].frequencyOfchar=frequency+1;    
                //System.out.println(c+" "+array[index].frequencyOfchar);
            }
            boolean flag=false;
            int firstPosition=Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            for(int i=0;i<256;i++){   

                // Step4         
                if(array[i].frequencyOfchar==1){
                    //System.out.println("character="+(char)(i+(int)'a'));
                    if(firstPosition> array[i].firstIndex){                    
                        firstPosition=array[i].firstIndex;
                        flag=true;
                    }
                }            
            }
            if(flag==true)
                System.out.println(str.charAt(firstPosition));
            else
                System.out.println("There is no such type of character");
        } 
    }
    class CharCountAndPosition{
        int firstIndex;
        int frequencyOfchar;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution in javascript with a lookup table:

```
var sample="It requires two scan of an array I want to find first non repeating character in only one scan";
var sampleArray=sample.split("");
var table=Object.create(null);
sampleArray.forEach(function(char,idx){
  char=char.toLowerCase();
  var pos=table[char];
  if(typeof(pos)=="number"){
    table[char]=sampleArray.length;  //a duplicate found; we'll assign some invalid index value to this entry and discard these characters later
    return;
  }
  table[char]=idx;  //index of first occurance of this character
});
var uniques=Object.keys(table).filter(function(k){
  return table[k]<sampleArray.length; 
}).map(function(k){
  return {key:k,pos:table[k]};
});
uniques.sort(function(a,b){
  return a.pos-b.pos;
});
uniques.toSource();         //[{key:"q", pos:5}, {key:"u", pos:6}, {key:"d", pos:46}, {key:"p", pos:60}, {key:"g", pos:66}, {key:"h", pos:69}, {key:"l", pos:83}]
(uniques.shift()||{}).key;  //q
```

Answer (score 0):

Following C prog, add char specific value to 'count' if char didn't occurred before, removes char specific value from 'count' if char had occurred before. At the end I get a 'count' that has char specific value which indicate what was that char!

```
//TO DO:
//If multiple unique char occurs, which one is occurred before? 
//Is is possible to get required values (1,2,4,8,..) till _Z_ and _z_?

#include <stdio.h>

#define _A_ 1
#define _B_ 2
#define _C_ 4 
#define _D_ 8
//And so on till _Z

//Same for '_a' to '_z'

#define ADDIFNONREP(C) if(count & C) count = count & ~C; else count = count | C; break;

char getNonRepChar(char *str)
{
        int i = 0, count = 0;
        for(i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
        {
                switch(str[i])
                {
                        case 'A':
                                ADDIFNONREP(_A_);
                        case 'B':
                                ADDIFNONREP(_B_);
                        case 'C':
                                ADDIFNONREP(_C_);
                        case 'D':
                                ADDIFNONREP(_D_);
                        //And so on
                        //Same for 'a' to 'z'
                }
        }
        switch(count)
        {
                case _A_:
                        return 'A';
                case _B_:
                        return 'B';
                case _C_:
                        return 'C';
                case _D_:
                        return 'D';
                //And so on
                //Same for 'a' to 'z'
        }
}

int main()
{
        char str[] = "ABCDABC";
        char c = getNonRepChar(str);
        printf("%c\n", c); //Prints D
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain a queue of keys as they are added to the hash map (you add your key to the queue if you add a new key to the hash map). After string scan, you use the queue to obtain the order of the keys as they were added to the map. This functionality is exactly what Java standard library class `OrderedHashMap` does.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take on the problem.

Iterate through string. Check if hashset contains the character. If so delete it from array. If not present just add it to the array and hashset.

```
NSMutableSet *repeated = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init]; //Hashset

NSMutableArray *nonRepeated = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; //Array

for (int i=0; i<[test length]; i++) {

    NSString *currentObj = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", [test characterAtIndex:i]]; //No support for primitive data types.

    if ([repeated containsObject:currentObj]) {
        [nonRepeated removeObject:currentObj];// in obj-c nothing happens even if nonrepeted in nil
        continue;
    }

    [repeated addObject:currentObj];

    [nonRepeated addObject:currentObj];

}

NSLog(@"This is the character %@", [nonRepeated objectAtIndex:0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can restrict yourself to strings of ASCII characters, I would recommend a **lookup table** instead of a hash table. This lookup table would have only 128 entries.

A possible approach would be as follows.

We start with an empty **queue** *Q* (may be implemented using linked lists) and a **lookup table** *T*. For a character *ch*, *T[ch]* stores a pointer to a queue node containing the character *ch* and the index of the first occurrence of *ch* in the string. Initially, all entries of *T* are `NULL`.

Each queue node stores the character and the first occurrence index as specified earlier, and also has a special boolean flag named *removed* which indicates that the node has been removed from the queue.

Read the string character by character. If the `i`<sup>th</sup> character is *ch*, check if *T[ch]* = `NULL`. If so, this is the first occurrence of *ch* in the string. Then add a node for *ch* containing the index `i` to the queue.

If *T[ch]* is not `NULL`, this is a repeating character. If the node pointed to by *T[ch]* has already been removed (i.e. the *removed* flag of the node is set), then nothing needs to be done. Otherwise, remove the node from the queue by manipulating the pointers of the previous and next nodes. Also set the *removed* flag of the node to indicate that the node is now removed. **Note** that we do not free/delete the node at this stage, nor do we set *T[ch]* back to `NULL`.

If we proceed in this way, the nodes for all the repeating characters will be removed from the queue. The *removed* flag is used to ensure that no node is removed twice from the queue if the character occurs more than two times.

After the string has been completely processed, the first node of the linked list will contain the character code as well as the index of the first non-repeating character. Then, the memory can be freed by iterating over the entries of lookup table *T* and freeing any non-`NULL` entries.

Here is a C implementation. Here, instead of the *removed* flag, I set the `prev` and `next` pointers of the current node to `NULL` when it is removed, and check for that to see if a node has already been removed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct queue_node {
    int ch;
    int index;
    struct queue_node *prev;
    struct queue_node *next;
};

void print_queue (struct queue_node *head);

int main (void)
{
    int i;
    struct queue_node *lookup_entry[128];
    struct queue_node *head;
    struct queue_node *last;
    struct queue_node *cur_node, *prev_node, *next_node;

    char str [] = "GeeksforGeeks";

    head = malloc (sizeof (struct queue_node));
    last = head;
    last->prev = last->next = NULL;

    for (i = 0; i < 128; i++) {
        lookup_entry[i] = NULL;
    }

    for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        cur_node = lookup_entry[str[i]];

        if (cur_node != NULL) {
            /* it is a repeating character */
            if (cur_node->prev != NULL) {
                /* Entry has not been removed. Remove it from the queue. */
                prev_node = cur_node->prev;
                next_node = cur_node->next;

                prev_node->next = next_node;
                if (next_node != NULL) {
                    next_node->prev = prev_node;
                } else {
                    /* Last node was removed */
                    last = prev_node;
                }

                cur_node->prev = NULL;
                cur_node->next = NULL;
                /* We will not free the node now. Instead, free
                 * all nodes in a single pass afterwards.
                 */ 
            }
        } else {
            /* This is the first occurence - add an entry to the queue */
            struct queue_node *newnode = malloc (sizeof(struct queue_node));

            newnode->ch = str[i];
            newnode->index = i;
            newnode->prev = last;
            newnode->next = NULL;
            last->next = newnode;
            last = newnode;

            lookup_entry[str[i]] = newnode;
        }
        print_queue (head);
    }

    last = head->next;
    while (last != NULL) {
        printf ("Non-repeating char: %c at index %d.\n", last->ch, last->index);
        last = last->next;
    }

    /* Free the queue memory */
    for (i = 0; i < 128; i++) {
        if (lookup_entry[i] != NULL) {
            free (lookup_entry[i]);
            lookup_entry[i] = NULL;
        }
    }
    free (head);

    return (0);
}

void print_queue (struct queue_node *head) {
    struct queue_node *tmp = head->next;

    printf ("Queue: ");
    while (tmp != NULL) {
        printf ("%c:%d ", tmp->ch, tmp->index);
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
    printf ("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making things more and more complex, I can use three for loops to tackle this.

```
class test{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        String s="STRESST";//Your input can be given here.
        char a[]=new char[s.length()];
    for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){
        a[i]=s.charAt(i);
    }

    for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){
        int flag=0;
       for(int j=0;j<s.length();j++){
            if(a[i]==a[j]){
             flag++;
            }
       }

        if(flag==1){
         System.out.println(a[i]+" is not repeated");
         break;
        }
    }
    }
}
```

I guess it will be helpful for people who are just gonna look at the logic part without any complex methods used in the program.

Comment: This is clearly O(n^2) which is not what he aimed for, and obviously noy one scan. Actually in the question you have a better solution than what you suggested

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in one Scan using the substring method. Do it like this:

```
String str="your String";<br>
String s[]= str.split("");<br>
int n=str.length();<br>
int i=0;<br><br>

for(String ss:s){
  if(!str.substring(i+1,n).contains(ss)){
    System.out.println(ss);
  }
}
```

This will have the lowest complexity and will search for it even without completing one full scan.

Comment: every time you call contains it is scanning all the string

Answer (score 0):

Add each character to a HashSet and check whether hashset.add() returns true, if it returns false ,then remove the character from hashset.
Then getting the first value of the hashset will give you the first non repeated character. 
**Algorithm:**

```
 for(i=0;i<str.length;i++)
{
 HashSet hashSet=new HashSet<>()
 if(!hashSet.add(str[i))
   hashSet.remove(str[i])
 }
 hashset.get(0) will give the non repeated character.
```

Comment: 1) Class HashSet does not have get() method. 
2) HashSet does not maintain order of insertion. 
3) In your code, declaration of  hashset "HashSet<Character> hashSet=new HashSet<>()"  should be outside the loop.
4) While fetching string's element use charAt()

Answer (score 0):

i have this program which is more simple, 
this is not using any data structures

```
public static char findFirstNonRepChar(String input){
    char currentChar = '\0';
    int len = input.length();
    for(int i=0;i<len;i++){
        currentChar = input.charAt(i);
        if((i!=0) && (currentChar!=input.charAt(i-1)) && (i==input.lastIndexOf(currentChar))){
            return currentChar;
        }
    }
    return currentChar;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple (non hashed) version...

```
public static String firstNRC(String s) {
    String c = "";
    while(s.length() > 0) {
        c = "" + s.charAt(0);
        if(! s.substring(1).contains(c)) return c;
        s = s.replace(c, "");
    }
    return "";
}
```

**or**

```
public static char firstNRC(String s) {
    s += " ";
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length() - 1; i++) 
        if( s.split("" + s.charAt(i)).length == 2 ) return s.charAt(i);
    return ' ';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

//This is the simple logic for finding first non-repeated character....

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        String s = "GeeksforGeeks";

        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {

            char begin = s.charAt(i);
            String begin1 = String.valueOf(begin);
            String end = s.substring(0, i) + s.substring(i + 1);

            if (end.contains(begin1));
            else {
                i = s.length() + 1;
                System.out.println(begin1);
            }

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Test
public void testNonRepeadLetter() {
    assertEquals('f', firstNonRepeatLetter("GeeksforGeeks"));
    assertEquals('I', firstNonRepeatLetter("teststestsI"));
    assertEquals('1', firstNonRepeatLetter("123aloalo"));
    assertEquals('o', firstNonRepeatLetter("o"));

}

private char firstNonRepeatLetter(String s) {
    if (s == null || s.isEmpty()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(s);
    }
    Set<Character> set = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        char charAt = s.charAt(i);
        if (set.contains(charAt)) {
            set.remove(charAt);
        } else {
            set.add(charAt);
        }
    }
    return set.iterator().next();
}
```

Comment: This returns the first character occurring an odd number of times - even if that number happens to be greater than one. (I'd prefer `if (!set.remove(charAt)) set.add(charAt);`)

Answer (score 0):

here is a tested code in java.  note that it is possible that no non repeated character is found, and for that we return a '0'

```
// find first non repeated character in a string
static char firstNR( String str){
    int i, j, l;
    char letter;
    int[] k = new int[100];

    j = str.length();

    if ( j > 100) return '0';

    for (i=0; i< j; i++){
        k[i] = 0;
    }

    for (i=0; i<j; i++){
        for (l=0; l<j; l++){
            if (str.charAt(i) == str.charAt(l))
                k[i]++;
        }
    }

    for (i=0; i<j; i++){
        if (k[i] == 1)
            return str.charAt(i);
    }

    return '0';
```

Answer (score 0):

Finding first non-repeated character  in one pass  O(n ) , without using indexOf and lastIndexOf methods

```
package nee.com;
public class FirstNonRepeatedCharacterinOnePass {

    public static void printFirstNonRepeatedCharacter(String str){
        String strToCaps=str.toUpperCase();
        char ch[]=strToCaps.toCharArray();
        StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
        // ASCII range for A-Z ( 91-65 =26)
        boolean b[]=new boolean[26];

        for(int i=0;i<ch.length;i++){
            if(b[ch[i]-65]==false){
                b[ch[i]-65]=true;               
            }
            else{
                //add repeated char to StringBuilder
                sb.append(ch[i]+"");
            }
        }
        for(int i=0;i<ch.length;i++){
            // if char is not there in StringBuilder means it is non repeated
            if(sb.indexOf(ch[i]+"")==-1){
                System.out.println(" first non repeated  in lower case ...."+Character.toLowerCase((ch[i])));
            break;
            }               
        }

    }
    public static void main(String g[]){
        String str="abczdabddcn";
        printFirstNonRepeatedCharacter(str);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the logic to find the first non-repeatable letter in a String.

```
String name = "TestRepeat";
        Set <Character> set = new LinkedHashSet<Character>();
        List<Character> list = new ArrayList<Character>();
        char[] ch = name.toCharArray();
        for (char c :ch) {
            set.add(c);
            list.add(c);
        }
        Iterator<Character> itr1 = set.iterator();
        Iterator<Character> itr2= list.iterator();

        while(itr1.hasNext()){
            int flag =0;
            Character  setNext= itr1.next();
            for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++){
                Character listNext= list.get(i);
                if(listNext.compareTo(setNext)== 0){
                    flag ++;
                }
            }

            if(flag==1){
                System.out.println("Character: "+setNext);
                break;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

it is very easy....you can do it without collection in java..

```
public class FirstNonRepeatedString{

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String input ="GeeksforGeeks";
        char process[] = input.toCharArray();
        boolean status = false;
        int index = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < process.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < process.length; j++) {

                if (i == j) {
                    continue;
                } else {
                    if (process[i] == process[j]) {
                        status = false;
                        break;
                    } else {
                        status = true;
                        index = i;
                    }
                }

            }
             if (status) {
            System.out.println("First non-repeated string is : " + process[index]);
            break;
        } 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can create LinkedHashMap having each character from the string and it's respective count. And then traverse through the map when you come across char with count as 1 return that character. Below is the function for the same.

```
private static char findFirstNonRepeatedChar(String string) {
    LinkedHashMap<Character, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    for(int i=0;i< string.length();i++){
        if(map.containsKey(string.charAt(i)))
            map.put(string.charAt(i),map.get(string.charAt(i))+1);
        else
            map.put(string.charAt(i),1);
    }

    for(Entry<Character,Integer> entry : map.entrySet()){
        if(entry.getValue() == 1){
            return entry.getKey();
        }
    }
    return ' ';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One Pass Solution.
I have used linked Hashmap here to maintain the insertion order. So I go through all the characters of a string and store it values in Linked HashMap. After that I traverse through the Linked Hash map and whichever first key will have its value equal to 1, I will print that key and exit the program.

```
    import java.util.*;
    class demo
    {
    public static void main(String args[])
     {
          String str="GeekGsQuizk";
          HashMap  <Character,Integer>hm=new LinkedHashMap<Character,Integer>();

                    for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++)
                      {
                       if(!hm.containsKey(str.charAt(i)))
                       hm.put(str.charAt(i),1);
                       else
                       hm.put(str.charAt(i),hm.get(str.charAt(i))+1);
                      }

           for (Character key : hm.keySet())
               {
                      if(hm.get(key)==1)
                   { 
                   System.out.println(key);
                   System.exit(0) ; 
                   }         

               }

         }
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this comes one year late, but I think if you use LinkedHashMap in your solution instead of using a HashMap, you will have the order guaranteed in the resulting map and you can directly return the key with the corresponding value as 1.

Not sure if this is what you wanted though as you will have to iterate over the map (not the string) after you are done populating it - but just my 2 cents.

Regards,

-Vini

Answer (score 0):

I did the same using LinkedHashSet. Following is the code snippet:

```
System.out.print("Please enter the string :");
str=sc.nextLine();
if(null==str || str.equals("")) {
   break;
}else {
   chArr=str.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
   set=new LinkedHashSet<Character>();
   dupSet=new LinkedHashSet<Character>();
   for(char chVal:chArr) {
    if(set.contains(chVal)) {
        dupSet.add(chVal);
    }else {
        set.add(chVal);
    }
   }
   set.removeAll(dupSet);
   System.out.println("First unique :"+set.toArray()[0]);
}
```

Comment: (Please present commented source code, only. Self-contained ready-to-run welcome - if you present a snippet, please make it syntactically correct (as in _close the block-else-statement_).)

Answer (score 0):

[You can find this question here](https://codefights.com/interview/7nbELjSu9Q4n6xviC/description)

For code of the below algorithm refer [this](http://ideone.com/l2fj2x) link (My implementation with test cases)

> Using **linkedlist** in combination with **hashMap**

I have a solution which solves it in **O(n) time** **One array pass** and **O(1) space**
Inreality -> O(1) space is O(26) space

Algorithm

1) **every time you visit a character for the first time**

Create a node for the linkedList(storing that character).Append it at the end of the lnkedList.Add an entry in the hashMap storing for recently appended charater the address of the node in the linked list that was before that character.If character is appended to an empty linked list store null for vale in hash map.

**2) Now if you encounter the same charactter again**

Remove that element from the linkedlist using the address stored in the hash map and now you have to update for the element that was after the deleted element ,the previous element for it. Make it equal to the previous element of the deleted element.

> **Complexity Analysis**
>
> LinkedlIst add element -> O(1)
>
> LinkedlIst delete element -> O(1)
>
> HashMap -> O(1)
>
> space O(1)
>
> pass -> one in O(n)

```
    #include<bits/stdc++.h>
    using namespace std;

    typedef struct node
    {
        char ch;
        node *next;
    }node;




    char firstNotRepeatingCharacter(string &s)
    {
      char ans = '_';
      map<char,node*> mp;//hash map atmost may consume O(26) space
      node *head = NULL;//linkedlist atmost may consume O(26) space
      node *last;// to append at last in O(1)
      node *temp1 = NULL;
      node *temp2 = new node[1];
      temp2->ch = '$';
      temp2->next = NULL;
      //This is my one pass of array//
      for(int i = 0;i < s.size();++i)
      {
        //first occurence of character//
        if(mp.find(s[i]) == mp.end())
        {
          node *temp = new node[1];
          temp->ch = s[i];
          temp->next = NULL;
          if(head == NULL)
          {
            head = temp;
            last = temp;
            mp.insert(make_pair(s[i],temp1));
          }
          else
          {
            last->next = temp;
            mp.insert(make_pair(s[i],last));
            last = temp; 
          }
        }
        //Repeated occurence//
        else
        {
          node *temp = mp[s[i]];
          if(mp[s[i]] != temp2)
          {
            if(temp == temp1)
            {
              head = head->next;
              if((head)!=NULL){mp[head->ch] = temp1;}
              else last = head;
              mp[s[i]] = temp2;
            }
            else if((temp->next) != NULL)
            {
              temp->next = temp->next->next;
              if((temp->next) != NULL){mp[temp->next->ch] = temp;}
              else last = temp;
              mp[s[i]] = temp2;
            }
            else
            {
              ;
            }
         }
        }
      if(head == NULL){;}
      else {ans = head->ch;}
      return ans;
    }

    int main()
    {
      int T;
      cin >> T;
      while(T--)
      {
      string str;
      cin >> str;
      cout << str << " ->  " << firstNotRepeatingCharacter(str)<< endl;
      }
      return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Requires one scan only.

Uses a deque (saves char) and a hashmap (saves char->node). On repeating char, get char's node in deque using hashmap and remove it from deque (in O(1) time) but keep the char in hashmap with null node value. `peek()` gives the 1st unique character.

```
[pseudocode]
char? findFirstUniqueChar(s):
    if s == null:
        throw
    deque<char>() dq = new
    hashmap<char, node<char>> chToNodeMap = new
    for i = 0, i < s.length(), i++:
        ch = s[i]
        if !chToNodeMap.hasKey(ch):
            chToNodeMap[ch] = dq.enqueue(ch)
        else:
            chNode = chToNodeMap[ch]
            if chNode != null:
                dq.removeNode(chNode)
                chToNodeMap[ch] = null
    if dq.isEmpty():
        return null
    return dq.peek()

// deque interface
deque<T>:
    node<T> enqueue(T t)
    bool removeNode(node<T> n)
    T peek()
    bool isEmpty()
```

Answer (score 0):

The string is scanned only once; other scans happen on counts and first appearance arrays, which are generally much smaller in size. Or at least below approach is for cases when string is much larger than character set the string is made from.

Here is an example in golang:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func firstNotRepeatingCharacter(s string) int {

    counts := make([]int, 256)
    first := make([]int, 256)

    // The string is parsed only once 
    for i := len(s) - 1; i >= 0; i-- {
        counts[s[i]]++
        first[s[i]] = i
    }

    min := 0
    minValue := len(s) + 1

    // Now we are parsing counts and first slices
    for i := 0; i < 256; i++ {
        if counts[i] == 1 && first[i] < minValue {
            minValue = first[i]
            min = i
        }
    }

    return min

}

func main() {

    fmt.Println(string(firstNotRepeatingCharacter("fff")))
    fmt.Println(string(firstNotRepeatingCharacter("aabbc")))
    fmt.Println(string(firstNotRepeatingCharacter("cbbc")))
    fmt.Println(string(firstNotRepeatingCharacter("cbabc")))

}
```

[go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/x5fDilcSIe6)

Answer (score 0):

Question : Find First Non Repeating Character or First Unique Character:

The code itself is understandable.

```
public class uniqueCharacter1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String a = "GiniGinaProtijayi";

        firstUniqCharindex(a);
    }

    public static void firstUniqCharindex(String a) {
        int count[] = new int[256];
        for (char ch : a.toCharArray()) {
            count[ch]++;
        } // for

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
            char ch = a.charAt(i);
            if (count[ch] == 1) {
                System.out.println(i);// 8
                System.out.println(a.charAt(i));// p
                break;
            }
        }

    }// end1
}
```

In Python:

```
def firstUniqChar(a):
  count = [0] * 256
  for i in a: count[ord(i)] += 1 
  element = ""
  for items in a:
      if(count[ord(items) ] == 1):
          element = items ;
          break
  return element


a = "GiniGinaProtijayi";
print(firstUniqChar(a)) # output is P
```

Answer (score 0):

> GeeksforGeeks also suggest efficient method but I think it is also two
>   scan.

Note that in the second scan, it does not scan the input string, but the array of wihch the length is `NO_OF_CHARS`.  So the time complexity is `O(n+m)`, which is better than `2*O(n)`, when the `n` is quite large(for a long intput string)

> But it requires two scan of an array. I want to find first
>   non-repeating character in only one scan.

IMHO, it is possible if a priority queue is used. In that queue we compare each char with its occurrence count and its first occur index, and finally, we simply get the first element in the queue. See @hlpPy 's answer.

Comment: Does this work ***without a second iteration of an array***? How is this different from geeksforgeeks proposed C solution quoted in the question?

Comment: @greybeard  Read the quoted C solution and found that my solution is the same. Sorry about that.  I cannot figure out a one iteration solution.

Comment: The interjection about the second scan was long overdue *somewhere* in this Q&A.

Comment: @greybeard `one scan of an array` is possible if a priority queue is used.  In that queue we compare each char with its count and first occur index. See @hlpPy 's answer.