# First Non Repeating Character using hashmap in one loop?

Tags: java, data-structures, hashmap

Recently an interviewer asked me to implement the first non repeating character in a string,I implemented it with hashmap using two different loops.Although the time complexity is O(n)+O(n),but he asked me to solve in a single loop.Can someone tells me how to do that?

Below is my implementation:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class firstnonrepeating {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String non = "nnjkljklhihis";

        Map<Character, Integer> m = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();

        for (int i = 0; i < non.length(); i++) {

            if (m.get(non.charAt(i)) != null) {
                m.put(non.charAt(i), m.get(non.charAt(i)) + 1);
            } else {
                m.put(non.charAt(i), 1);
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < non.length(); i++) {

            if (m.get(non.charAt(i)) == 1) {
                System.out.println("First Non Reapeating Character is "
                        + non.charAt(i));
                break;
            } else {
                if (i == non.length() - 1)
                    System.out.println("No non repeating Character");
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I think this is a question more suited for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Given a string, find its first non-repeating character in only One scan](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26750939/given-a-string-find-its-first-non-repeating-character-in-only-one-scan)

Answer (score 2):

```
    String non = "nnnjkljklhihis";
    Map<String,LinkedHashSet<Character>> m = new   HashMap<String,LinkedHashSet<Character>>() ;
    m.put("one", new LinkedHashSet<Character>());
    m.put("else", new LinkedHashSet<Character>());
    m.put("all", new LinkedHashSet<Character>());
    for (int i = 0; i < non.length(); i++) {
        if (m.get("all").contains(non.charAt(i))) {
            m.get("one").remove(non.charAt(i));
            m.get("else").add(non.charAt(i));
        } else {
            m.get("one").add(non.charAt(i));
            m.get("all").add(non.charAt(i));
        }
    }
    if(m.get("one").size()>0){
        System.out.println("first non repeatant : "+m.get("one").iterator().next());
    }
```

Comment: He said he needed to use a HashMap.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String characters = "nnjkljklhihis";
        Character firstNonRepeatingChar = getFirstNonRepeatingCharacter(characters);
        if(firstNonRepeatingChar == null)
        {
            System.out.println("No non repeating characters in " + characters);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("The first non repeating character is " + firstNonRepeatingChar);
        }
    }

    private static Character getFirstNonRepeatingCharacter(String characters)
    {
        Map<Integer, Character> m = new HashMap<Integer, Character>();
        for(int i = 0; i < characters.length(); i++)
        {
            Character currentChar = characters.charAt(i);
            if(i > 0)
            {
                Character previousChar = m.get(i-1);
                if(!previousChar.equals(currentChar))
                {
                    return currentChar;
                }
            }
            m.put(i, currentChar);
        }
        return null;//No non repeating character found
    }
}
```

Comment: I assumed repeating meant that it was consecutively repeating. Maybe I misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

This is the same answer as Osama, re-written in a more modern way.

```
public static Optional<Character> getFirstNonRepeatingCharacter(String characters) {
    HashMap<Character, Consumer<Character>> map = new HashMap<>();
    LinkedHashSet<Character> set = new LinkedHashSet<>();
    for(char c: characters.toCharArray()) {
        map.merge(c, set::add, (_1, _2) ->  set::remove).accept(c);
    }
    return set.stream().findFirst();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One more possible solution to this:

```
   public class FirstNonRepeatingCharacterInString {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Character character = firstNonRepeatingCharacter("nnjkljklhihis");
        System.out.println("First Non repeating character :  " + character != null ? character : null);
    }

    private static Character firstNonRepeatingCharacter(String arg) {
        char[] characters = arg.toCharArray();
        Map<Character, Character> set = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        // cost of the operation is O(n)
        for (char c : characters) {
            if (set.containsKey(c)) {
                set.remove(c);
            } else {
                set.put(c, c);
            }
        }
        //here we are just getting the first value from collection
        // not iterating the whole collection and the cost of this operation is O(1)
        Iterator<Character> iterator = set.keySet().iterator();
        if (iterator.hasNext()) {
            return iterator.next();
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In this solution, if the containsKey(c) returns true, i.e. the character has been seen earlier, then you should not just remove it from the LinkedHashMap. After removing it, you should put it back again so that it goes to the end in iteration order. Otherwise, the second time you see that character, it will not be in the LinkedHashMap, so you will put it back. For example, iterating over, say, "abbaac":

Comment: e.g. `"abbaac"`: `a` added. `b` added. `b` removed. `a` removed. `a` added. `c` added. Map now has `a` and `c`. Since `a` was added first, it will be returned as the 1st unique char - which is clearly wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Given a string, find its first non-repeating character:

```
public class Test5 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String a = "GiniSoudiptaGinaProtijayi";
    Map<Character, Long> map = a.chars().mapToObj(
            ch -> Character.valueOf((char)ch)
            ).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),
                    LinkedHashMap:: new,
                    Collectors.counting()
                    ));


        System.out.println(map);
    //List<Character> list = map.entrySet().stream().filter( entry -> entry.getValue() == 1    )
        //.map(entry -> entry.getKey()).collect(Collectors.toList());

                //System.out.println(list);
        Character ch =  map.entrySet().stream()
                .filter( entry -> entry.getValue() == 1L    )
                .map(entry -> entry.getKey()).findFirst().get();
        System.out.println(ch);

}
}
```